# Upload a file using Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

Using PowerShell 7, I successfully upload a file with Invoke-RestMethod:

```
$Uri = '...(my url)...'
$File = '...(path to my file)...'
$Form = @{
    f = Get-Item -Path $File
}
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Form $Form -StatusCodeVariable 'HttpStatus'
```

I'd like to do the same with Invoke-WebRequest; I prefer Invoke-WebRequest because its returned value has a convenient structure with a status and a content fields inside, so I can get rid of $HttpStatus variable and simply convert a result to JSON with '$Result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json'.

There is an example of uploading in the documentation on Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7 , Example 6. But it uses the Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet. Isn't this a typo in the docs? Can I use Invoke-WebRequest as simply as in the Invoke-RestMethod example?

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod` is essentially a wrapper for `Invoke-WebRequest` which takes the `Content` property and tries to apply `ConvertFrom-Json` on it.  In other words, you can normally substitute `iwr` for `irm` anywhere you see it, but you will have the extra step of converting the response from `JSON` or `XML` or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully replaced the cmdlet in my code with Invoke-WebRequest:

```
$Result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Form $Form -SkipHttpErrorCheck
$httpStatus = $Result.StatusCode
if ($httpStatus -eq 200)
{
    $j = $Result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
    . . . .
}
```

FoxDeploy, your comment was quite helpful. Thank you.